# javafx buttons some part of text hiding on hover

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2

I am using javafx 2.2 for my desktop application.

The problem I am facing is that when I hover on the buttons some of the part of text gets hidden. The problem is only on some of the machines. Attached is a screenshot of the save button. The **text (Save) gets hidden when I focus or hover on the button.**

[image: button hover issue]

I tried removing the button: hover CSS but now when I click on it, then I get the issue.

Comment: You would get much more help if you could post a simple piece of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: actually this is not reproducible easily...It comes on some of machines and not others.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried removing the button: hover CSS but now when I click on it,
>   then I get the issue.

Its hard to diagnose the cause with no code provided, however given that by removing the hover styling you removed the behaviour on hover, have you also tried removing the `:focus` and `:active` classes? These are typically assigned during a click event.

What you may also want to do is take the hover class you removed, look at the properties and remove each one at a time to find the culprit- if this doesnt work there is likely some other runtime manipulation of the element happening, it'll be impossible to chase up without code unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure what part of the application code should i paste here..because i am not sure what might caz this issue. The Ui is defined in fxml files..I have extracted caspian.css and added our customm css to it...The application is deployed on few machines and this issue is only coming on my machine on all the Buttons and textfields when i select the text...I guess it could be related to the graphics settings on my machine....